# 'TABLE 607 WHERE `Non_unique` = 1' - Setup Upgrade Error

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, database, database-schema

When i run this command (setup:upgrade) in Magento 2. Then i am getting this error.

**Please tell me how to i can fix this issue. which table is 607 ?**

Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'TABLE 607 WHERE `Non_unique` = 1' at line 1, query was: SHOW INDEXES FROM TABLE 607 WHERE `Non_unique` = 1

Screenshot is attached. [image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Same Problem here:

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'TABLE 564 WHERE `Non_unique` = 1' at line 1, query was: SHOW INDEXES FROM TABLE 564 WHERE `Non_unique` = 1
```

Comment: I have resolved my issue - check your database there you 'll see (TABLE 564) export in CSV and than you can easily configure your error.